# The command "backup:run" does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-backup

I have faced a problem when I am run the command from my code, My code is fine, I have test the code, Because when I run this `Artisan::call('view:clear');` then its working, But when I run this `Artisan::call('backup:run');` Browser told me: **The command "backup:run" does not exist.**
Note: when I am run this `php artisan backup:run` using cmd then it's working, I will be grateful, If you guys help me, Thank you
Here is my All code of controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

class BackupController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            Artisan::call('backup:run');

            return 'Done';

        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to register backup:run in console command and it's kernel that is customize command

Comment: view:clear is built in laravel artisan command

Comment: I am new at laravel can you help to solve this problem Please sir, I will be grateful to you.

Comment: One thing sir, When I am run the `php artisan backup:run` from cmd then its work, Please check this screenshot : https://prnt.sc/10l4kop

Comment: are u use spatie-laravel-backup package

Comment: Yes, I used spatie-laravel-backup

Comment: sure that package publish on server

Comment: Yes, Sir, Can you give me any contact info, Then I can contact you and let your know everything in detail, I will be grateful sir.

Comment: mail:mostafagoda199@gmail.com whatsapp : +201205603465